# V8 won't optimize more than 4 object types?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, v8

So I was watching Franziska Hinkelmann's [talk on the V8 engine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p-iiEDtpy6I).

She comments at 20:03 that the V8 engine will not optimize if there are more than four object types. I am just starting out in node.js, so I don't have any experience in these matters, but four seems like a very low number. Wouldn't OO software usually involve more than four object types?

I'm aware that V8 has limitations on the number of properties an object can have for fast processing (8, also seems low).

Comment: I might interject that if you're just starting out in nodejs, you probably have 1000 more important things to learn about node.js and Javascript, in general, than V8 optimization.

Comment: Agreed, but I'm a plan-ahead kind of person. If V8 is not compatible with ordinary OOP, that's something that needs to be taken into account.

Comment: Uhhh, V8 is perfectly compatible with ordinary OOP.  There are millions of lines of code doing extensive OOP and V8 is probably the best engine out there for performance.  99.9999% of code simply doesn't care about the level of optimization you are concerning yourself about.  It would be useful to learn a few programming "don'ts" that spoil optimization, but if you just program in strict mode, you'll be well on your way to that.  And program away in OOP and nodejs will perform just fine.

Comment: Also, just because V8 has certain optimizations to make things very fast in certain circumstances doesn't mean you can't write code that wouldn't be able to use all those optimizations.  This is what optimizing compilers do.  They look for things they know they can optimize (that fit some pattern they've designed for) and they massively speed it up.  99.9999% of the time, we don't need to concern ourselves with that and certainly not when first learning the language.  There are so many other things that affect the quality of your end result far, far more than the level you're asking about now.

Comment: I would suggest you read this: [Optimization killers](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers) and avoid those in all your coding (perhaps with an occasional conscious exception when there isn't another way and you accept the consequences).  But, I wouldn't spend any time worrying about how many properties you have on an object.

Comment: Thanks for your time and the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V8 developer here. In the talk you are referencing, the situation Franziska is referring to is when *a single place in your code* (e.g. a single `do_something_with(obj.prop);`) sees more than four types (for `obj`), it switches to a different mode. That's not the same as "doesn't optimize" -- on the contrary, when V8 detects this pattern, it optimizes for it; it just so happens that optimizing for highly polymorphic code requires a different approach than optimizing for monomorphic code.

And as jfriend00 already commented, you most probably don't have to worry about this internal detail.

Also, for the record, the number of properties that an object can have in fast-to-access/slow-to-create configuration is about 1,000. (It's another case where there isn't a "good"/"fast" and a "bad"/"slow" state, it's rather "optimize for one" or "optimize for the other".)